# Does parallel version of Z3 work for BV logic?

Tags: parallel-processing, z3

I could not utilize both cores of the processor with parallel Z3 3.2 (from bin_mt or x64_mt directory) with `PAR_NUM_THREADS=2` on Windows7. The same 50% and no time difference with single threaded version.

Is parallel version supported for these logics or it works with QF_IDL only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mistake, parallel execution hasn't been included in Z3 3.2. That's why Z3 still runs sequentially when you set `PAR_NUM_THREADS=2`. <strike>Z3 team has corrected the mistake so parallel feature will be available in the next release.</strike>

**EDIT:**

As @Leo mentioned in the comment, parallel feature is now planned for Z3 4.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plan changed, this feature will be back in the release following the next one :-(  The next release will be Z3 4.0. The parallel execution support is now planned for version 4.1. Sorry about that.